# SQL Query to Find JobID

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am looking to write an SQL query to find the JobID for journey sends. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sql have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what other fields you need apart from Job ID and Journey ID, you can play around with the following:

```
SELECT
s.JobID,
j.VersionID
FROM _Sent s INNER JOIN _JourneyActivity j
ON j.JourneyActivityObjectID = s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! What if i wanted to get EmailName also?

Comment: EmailName is a part of the _Job data view, so you would have to add one more join to join _Sent data view with _Job data view on sent JobID = job JobID